# Inverting colors in emacs

Tags: themes

Is there any extension or easy way to invert colors in emacs?

I tend to show code a lot through screen sharing and often a light theme is better while the dark is more comfortable for me to work alone.

Comment: `M-x invert-face RET default RET`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two different color themes and switch between them.

```el
(global-set-key [f5] (lambda () (interactive) (load-theme 'sanityinc-tomorrow-day t)))
(global-set-key [f6] (lambda () (interactive) (load-theme 'sanityinc-tomorrow-night t)))
```

Comment: You cannot switch to themes directly using their names. An elisp call to load a theme is of the type `(load-theme 'THEME-NAME t)`. That has to be wrapped in `(lambda () (interactive) .. )` if binding directly to a key.

Comment: @kaushalmodi In case of `color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow-...` this works. But I've changed my answer as you suggested.

Comment: Ah. That theme then might have those wrapper functions built in. Generally theme packages do not have such wrapper functions.

Comment: You could also just use `M-x` `enable-theme`

Answer (score 2):

There's a `-rv` switch you can use to boot up Emacs in reverse video mode, however I've found it not to work in combination with custom themes.

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks about "inverting colors", which I interpret as "complementing colors". But then you also talk about themes.

- You can use library [Palette](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorPalette) ([`palette.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/palette.el)) to obtain the complement of any color in a WYSIWYG way (so you can easily tweak the result if you like).
- You can use library [`hexrgb.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hexrgb.el) to obtain the complement of any color programmatically (command `hexrgb-complement`).
- You can use library [Do Re Mi](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi) or library [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) to incrementally adjust colors or face foregrounds/backgrounds.
- You can use these things (above) to define a new theme starting from an existing theme.
- You can use library [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) to cycle among existing themes ([color themes or custom themes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorAndCustomThemes)).